# C++ code doesn't run while using fftw library

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, fftw

I am trying to implement a DFT using the fftw library ([link to FFTW documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/index.html#SEC_Contents)).

All the libraries have been correctly linked, and the project builds just fine. However, the code doesn't run the moment any function from the fftw library is called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int vectorSize = 100;
    cout << vectorSize << endl;

    fftw_complex vec[vectorSize], vecOut[vectorSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) {
        vec[i][0] = i;
        vec[i][1] = 1;
    }

    // Call to function to create an FFT plan
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(vectorSize, vec, vecOut, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    cout << "test" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment the line where the fftw_plan is instantiated, the code outputs 100 and "test" as expected. There are no issues in the build, as far as I can tell. I haven't really been able to find any post which describes a similar problem.

I am running this on eclipse, using MinGW and the 32 bit version of the pre-compiled binary available for windows ([download link](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html)).

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: What happens if you hit _Pause_ on the debugger? Is the code still running or does it crash out on the call to `fftw_plan_dft_1d`. Have you tried other fftw calls, more simpler ones? The [documentation I found](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html) suggests calls to `fftw_malloc`, so I'm not sure if creating your `fftw_complex` on the stack is causing issues or not. I suggest trying a simpler function call to see if it works.

Comment: The debugger terminates out of turn, and never reaches any breakpoint I put in the code.

Comment: Just want to re-iterate, the code doesn't "crash" per se. It doesn't output anything, I'm not sure if it's even working in the background (my guess is it is, because there are no errors)

Answer (score 0):

Fftw requires input/output to be 16-byte aligned. When you declare the arrays on stack, this can't be guaranteed. So you need to call fftw_malloc or other function to allocate the arrays. Also, your code only creates the plan but doesn't execute it, thus no fft is carried out on the input data.

Comment: I realize I'm not executing the fft algorithm all the way through. The reason I uploaded this snippet was to show that irrespective of whichever call I make to the library (including fftw_malloc()) results in no output being generated.

Comment: That is curious. I used VS2017 to compile and link your code and it runs okay. Something wrong with your mingw installation or lib generation?

Comment: Yeah, I figured there might be a conflict with the mingw version or something. Thanks, though ... I think I'll try working with Visual Studio :)